# Where do I put imports that would normally go in main.ts, when I am doing lazy module loading?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, codemirror

In my Angular app, I would like to use the library CodeMirror inside a Lazily Loaded module.

The trouble I am having is that the [CodeMirror documentation](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-codemirror#use) tell me to

> In your main.ts or at the root of your application, see documentation:
>
> `import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';`
> `import 'codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown';`

> Import the base css file and your
> theme
>
> `@import '~codemirror/lib/codemirror'; @import '~codemirror/theme/material';`

However I would prefer this code **NOT** be imported throughout my app since it is only used by one lazy module.

What can I do so that this is imported correctly only when needed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the main idea of the library scripts import is that they come after the app is initialized and apparently it's working in an old fashioned way with the `window` object.

Therefore I could suggest you having a service with kind of `init` method. It would insert scripts from a CDN into the `head`, then report back when those are loaded. Then you are good to go. But you would need to defer this component's creation till the scripts are downloaded as it looks for the `CodeMirror` when created (see [source](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-codemirror/blob/master/src/lib/codemirror.component.ts#L106)).

Answer (score 0):

Some packages are needed to be imported in root like `hammerjs`.

My suggestion is to just do it as the way they said or import it in `angular.json`.

```
{
  "scripts": [
    ...,

    "node_modules/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js",
    "node_modules/codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown.js"
  ],
  "styles": [
    ...,

    "node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.scss",
    "node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.scss"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng2-codemirror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-codemirror).

So install `CodeMirror` library in your application like this:

```
npm install ng2-codemirror --save
```

Now import `CodemirrorModule` in your module which is subject to be lazily loaded:

```
import { CodemirrorModule } from 'ng2-codemirror';

...

@NgModule({
  ... 
  imports:      [
    CodemirrorModule,
    ...
  ],
  ... 
})
export class MyLazyModule { }
```

Then import the styles and scripts in your `angular.json` file like this:

```
"styles": [
   "node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css",      
   "node_modules/codemirror/theme/material.css"
   ...
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js",
    "node_modules/codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown.js"
    ...
  ]
```